# Unexpected result of C++ program

Tags: c++

I have created a C++ which compiles successfully, but when I run it I get `c=0`. 
 Can anybody explain why?

```
int main()
{
   double U0, U, C, A, B, D;
   U = 0.2;
   A = U/U0;
   B = 1+1/(16*pow(A, 2));
   D = pow(B, 2)-(1/4)*A;
   for (U0=0.2; U0<=1; U0=U0+0.2)
   {
      if (U <= (4*U0)) 
      { 
         C= (1/2)*(B+sqrt(D));
         cout <<" | U0 | "<< U0 <<" | U | "<< U <<" | C^2 | "<< C << endl;
         U = U + 0.2;
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: To begin with `1/4` is an *integer* division. Same with `1/2`. The results will *always* be equal to zero. I suggest you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), and split up your expressions into smaller sub-expressions. That way issue like this will be very easy to find when debugging.

Comment: There is also the use of the *uninitialised variable* `U0` in `A = U/U0;`

Comment: @john I'm sure OP knows about that; because I'm sure OP has all the warnings enabled on their compiler, and reads the compiler output....

Comment: Use of FP types in loop control:(   Is this 'spot the bugs' homework?

Answer (score 2):

Because of these kind of statements:

```
C= (1/2)*(B+sqrt(D));
```

C++ interprets `1/2` as an integer operation (not a floating one), hence `1/2 = 0` (for integers)

This is an error everybody has done once in his life!

After you will always write something like `1/2.` with the dot to force a division using the `double` type.

Comment: Simpler to write `0.5` instead of `1/2.`.

Comment: yes, sure, however, the dot trick is still useful in `1/(1.+n)` for instance. As a complement to my answer, also note that `1/2.f` will force `float` usage instead of `double` type.

Comment: @PicaudVincent   If you're looking something that's more readable, `1f/n`

Comment: Thanks.Now type of result is inf